# Can SSL context options be set when using Twisted endpoints?

Tags: python, ssl, twisted, pyopenssl

I am writing a server in Python+Twisted that uses the endpoints [1] to allow configuring the listening connection.  The documentation doesn't show any obvious (to me!) way to set options for an SSL context object using an endpoint string.  I poked around in the source, and it looks like the `IStreamServerEndpoint` object returned for an SSL connection has something like a `_context` attribute I could fiddle with, but that seems kind of kludgy.  I was wondering if there is some way for me to set the SSL context options without having to hack the endpoint internals.  (I want to set the context up to be able to verify a client certificate).

Thanks,
Carl

[1] https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/endpoints.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`twisted.internet.endpoints.SSL4ServerEndpoint` accepts an argument to its initializer, `sslContextFactory`.  This object is used to create the TLS context used by connections established to that server endpoint.

If you supply your own context factory then it can configure the context objects in any way you like prior to giving them back to the endpoint.

Comment: Is there any way to use endpoints.SSL4ServerEndpoint while still making use of an endpoint **string**?  I.e. can I still use endpoints.serverFromString() and then somehow shoehorn in a context?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  If you got a server from `serverFromString`, you have no idea if it even supports TLS, let alone what context parameters it has.  Do you just want to use `serverFromString` but validate client certificates?

Comment: Yes.  Ideally, there would be something I could put in the endpoint string like `ssl:...:cert=...:key=...:verify_peers=1` (param names might be wrong).  I want to be able to configure the endpoint to accept a client SSL cert, but I don't want to have to reinvent all the nice parsing that went into endpoints.

Comment: This would make a reasonable enhancement to the TLS endpoint string description.  You can also write your own endpoint parser plugins and have them set up the TLS context however you like (and support whatever options you like).